# VAO drawing the wrong Index Buffer

Tags: opengl, vao

I'm trying to draw multiple objects with a (the same) basic shader program. The objects have vertex buffers that I intend to draw using associated index buffers by calling glDrawElements. I've set up a VAO for each object and thought I'd associated the index buffer and vertex buffer with the VAO, but when I draw the second (and any additional objects) they are drawn using the wrong vertices.

Here's my (pseudoish) code for setting up the VBO's and EBO's:

```
glGenBuffers(1, &vboCube);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboCube);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, getNumSphereVertices() * sizeof(Vertex), &data[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

glGenBuffers(1, &iboCube);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iboCube);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, getNumCubeIndices() * sizeof(uint32), &data[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);


glGenBuffers(1, &vboSphere);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboSphere);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, getNumSphereVertices() * sizeof(Vertex), &data[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

glGenBuffers(1, &iboSphere);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iboSphere);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, getNumSphereIndices() * sizeof(uint32), &data[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

**Edit**:
These have been updated to use DSA equivalents and the problem persists. DSA code as per:

```
glCreateBuffers(1, &vboCube);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboCube);
glNamedBufferData(vboCube, getNumCubeVertices() * sizeof(Vertex), &data[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

Next linking my program attributes:

```
glUseProgram(programID);

uint32 vaoCube;
glCreateVertexArrays(1, &vaoCube);
glBindVertexArray(vaoCube);
i = 0
for each attribute:
    uint32 attribIndex = glGetAttribLocation(program, name.c_str());
    glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(vaoCube, i, vboCube, 0, stride);
    glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(vaoCube, attribIndex);
    glVertexArrayAttribFormat(vaoCube, attribIndex, numCells, dataType, normalise, offset);
    glVertexArrayAttribBinding(vaoCube, attribIndex, i);
    glVertexArrayBindingDivisor(vaoCube, i, divisor);
    i++
glBindVertexArray(0);

glBindVertexArray(vaoCube);
glVertexArrayElementBuffer(vaoCube, iboCube);
glBindVertexArray(0);


uint32 vaoSphere;
glCreateVertexArrays(1, &vaoSphere);
glBindVertexArray(vaoSphere);
i = 0
for each attribute:
    uint32 attribIndex = glGetAttribLocation(program, name.c_str());
    glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(vaoSphere, i, vboSphere, 0, stride);
    glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(vaoSphere, attribIndex);
    glVertexArrayAttribFormat(vaoSphere, attribIndex, numCells, dataType, normalise, offset);
    glVertexArrayAttribBinding(vaoSphere, attribIndex, i);
    glVertexArrayBindingDivisor(vaoSphere, i, divisor);
    i++
glBindVertexArray(0);

glBindVertexArray(vaoSphere);
glVertexArrayElementBuffer(vaoSphere, iboSphere);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

And finally drawing the objects:

```
glBindVertexArray(vaoCube);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, getNumCubeIndices(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (GLvoid*)0);
glBindVertexArray(0);


glBindVertexArray(vaoSphere);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, getNumSphereIndices(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (GLvoid*)0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Finally the result:

[image: Cube and sphere]

Is the VAO setup incorrect?

Comment: @Rabbid76 sorry, that was a bad code to question conversion. vertexBufferBinding is the binding point of the VBO (vboCube and vboSphere in this instance). I've edited the code snippet to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ARB_direct_state_access/OpenGL 4.5, you should do so consistently and entirely. So all of that stuff in "my (pseudoish) code for setting up the VBO's and EBO's:" is wrong. You should be using `glCreateBuffer`, `glNamedBufferData` and the like.

This is important because while `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` is part of context state, `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` is part of VAO state. And if you're using core OpenGL and don't have a VAO bound... that means there is no element array buffer state. So your `glBindBuffer` call should have errored out, and your subsequent attempts to use them would similarly fail.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've updated the buffer creation and fill funcs to the DSA method. Interestingly I wasn't getting any GL errors with the other setup. The issue with the mangled sphere persists though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was external to the code shown above. The above code actually works.